# For loop using package stratification

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to write a for loop to get the results of 30 populations.
Those populations were imported by:

```
 nomes<-list.files(pattern=".txt$")
 dados<-list()

 for (i in 1:length(nomes))
 {
   dados[[i]]<-read.table(nomes[i])
 }
 names(dados)<-nomes
```

So I have 30 populations in one data frame.
I have to find the cv of samples with dalenius hodges methods. Any way, this is not important. The important thing is the loop that I am not doing right. I have tried this:

```
 for (i in nomes)
 {
 #H=3
 dh[[i]] <- strata.cumrootf(x = dados[[i]]$V1, Ls = 3, alloc = c(0.5, 0, 0.5), n=100)
 vardh[[i]] <- sum((dh[[i]]$var*dh[[i]]$Nh/(dh[[i]]$Nh-1))*(dh[[i]]$Nh*(dh[[i]]$Nh-dh[[i]]$nh)/dh[[i]]$nh))
 cvdh[[i]] <- sqrt(vardh[[i]])/sum(dados[[i]]$V1)
```

}

But it didnt work. This function is in the "stratification" package.

The error that appear is this:

Error in dh[[i]] <- strata.cumrootf(x = dados[[i]]$V1, Ls = 3, alloc = c(0.5,  : 
  object 'dh' not found
In addition: Warning message:
'nclass' value has been chosen arbitrarily

Can anybody help me?
Thanks.

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: THis is the error message:Error in dh[[i]] <- strata.cumrootf(x = dados[[i]]$V1, Ls = 3, alloc = c(0.5,  : 
  object 'dh' not found
In addition: Warning message:
'nclass' value has been chosen arbitrarily

Comment: This error message means the variable do not exist. You have to create an empty list first